# Trouble with navigation between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've added a tap event handler for a list item in a list,and my xaml code for that is given below

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="612" Margin="6,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Height="50" Tap="StackPanel_Tap_1" >
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="300" Height="44" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbEmail" Width="100" Height="44" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

And my c# code is,

```
private void StackPanel_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Now when I tap on the list, my navigation fails and function automatically executes the following inbuilt function in App.xaml.cs

```
 private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

What is the problem? And how should I rectify it?

Comment: Most likely the URI `/ExpenseDetail.xaml` isn't valid -- you will have to check the actual exception details contained in `e` to know for sure.

Comment: @McGarnagle the problem was with uri only, it was in a folder.
So i changed the uri as "/Folder/Page2.xaml"

Comment: And did this work for you?

Comment: ya that worked for me... my file name was 'Page2' and it was in the folder named 'folder' so the uri "**/Folder/Page2.xaml**" worked perfectly fine!